# In which WWDC session video did Apple show the API for localized time interval formatting?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdate, foundation

A long time ago I watched a WWDC session video where Apple introduced an API which would print a time interval in a humanly readable, localized form.

Instead of printing a date when someone posted a comment, it was very easy to print a localized string such as "2 hours ago" or "Yesterday" or "Last week".

I can't find that video anymore and no references or examples for this API. I'm sure that it was a dedicated API to directly get this kind of localized strings for date intervals relative to the current date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't remember the video (although there was some video about it) but I think the API you are thinking of is:

`[NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:date dateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle]`

I'm not sure if this API does relative date formatting and the frameworks mentioned by `Midhun MP` take this a lot further

You can, of course, construct your own `NSDateFormatter` and set the `setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:YES` property to provide text like "Today" or "Tomorrow".

Example code is in the class reference below in `setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:`.

See [NSDateFormatterClassReference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about that video.

There is an open source library available for doing this: [**SEHumanizedTimeDiff**](https://github.com/sarperdag/SEHumanizedTimeDiff).

Also check Three20's [**NSDateAdditions**](https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/src/Three20Core/Sources/NSDateAdditions.m).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're after session 244 from 2012.

Called "Internationalisation Tips and Tricks".

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't address this issue. Must have been another session. People were chanting and applauding to it.

Comment: Ah, it might have been a keynote thing then. A "reveal" or "sneak peek" rather than a WWDC. People tend to cheer more at them.